# The integral $\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{e^{-x^2}}{(1+e^x)^2} dx$.

Tags: improper-integrals, special-functions, gaussian-integral

Let
$$T(n) = \int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{e^{-x^2}}{(1+e^{x})^n} dx.$$

We have that
$$ T(0) = \sqrt{\pi} \text{ and } T(1) = \frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2}$$
and also that
$$ T(3) = \tfrac{3}{2} T(2) - \frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{4}.$$
Can we find a closed form for $T(2)$? It would also give us $T(3)$. Perhaps something in terms of special functions?

Comment: Sorry, there is a error in my answer: At the end, we get a result that depend on the parity of $n$, and this gives not the answer to your question. Sorry again.

Comment: Hm. What was your idea? You must have deleted your answer.

Comment: OK; The Idea: Let $0\leq k \leq n$, $n\geq 1$. 1) By a change $u=-x$ we prove that $T(k)=\int_{\mathbb{R}}\exp(-u^2)\frac{\exp(ku)}{(1+\exp(u))^k}du=\int_{\mathbb{R}}\exp(-u^2)\frac{\exp(ku)(1+\exp(u))^{n-k}}{(1+\exp(u))^n}du$
2) For $y\in \mathbb{R}$, we have $\sum_{k=0}^n \binom{k}{n}y^kT(k)=\int_{\mathbb{R}}\exp(-u^2)\frac{(1+(y+1)\exp(u))^n}{(1+\exp(u))^n}du$ 3) Put $y=-1$. This is here that there is a problem with the parity (if $n$ is even, $T_n$ disappear, but not if $n$ is odd; I have written that $T_n$ always disappear).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An expression for $T(2)$ as a series of Bernoulli numbers:
\begin{align}
T(2) &= \int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{e^{-x^2}}{(1+e^{x})^2} d\,dx\\
 &=\frac{1}{4}\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{e^{-x^2-x}}{\cosh^2 \frac{x}{2}} \,dx\\
&=\frac{1}{2}\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{e^{-4x^2-2x}}{\cosh^2 x} \,dx\\
 &=\frac{1}{2}\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{e^{-4x^2+2x}}{\cosh^2 x} \,dx
\end{align}
Summing the last two expressions and using the formula $\cosh 2x=2\cosh^2x-1$, it comes
\begin{align}
T(2)&=\frac{1}{2}\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{\cosh 2x}{\cosh^2 x}e^{-4x^2}\,dx\\
&=\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-4x^2}\,dx-\frac{1}{2}\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{e^{-4x^2}}{\cosh^2 x}\,dx\\
&=\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2}-\frac{1}{2}\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{e^{-4x^2}}{\cosh^2 x}\,dx
\end{align}
We integrate by parts,
\begin{equation}
T(2)=\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2}-4\int_{-\infty}^\infty xe^{-4x^2}\tanh x\,dx
\end{equation} 
Now, using the series expansion for $\tanh$ [DLMF](http://dlmf.nist.gov/4.33.E3):
\begin{equation}
\tanh z=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{2^{2n}(2^{2n}-1)B_{2n}}{(2n)!}z^{2n-1}
\end{equation} 
one can express, 
\begin{align}
T(2)&=\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2}-4\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{2^{2n}(2^{2n}-1)B_{2n}}{(2n)!}\int_{-\infty}^\infty x^{2n}e^{-4x^2}\,dx\\
&=\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2}-2\sqrt{\pi}\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{2^{2n}-1}{2^{2n}}\frac{B_{2n}}{n!}
\end{align} 
where we have used the tabulated formula
\begin{equation}
\int_0^\infty x^{2n}e^{-px^2}\,dx=\frac{(2n-1)!!}{2(2p)^n}\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{p}}
\end{equation}